# Minimize $x_1 + x_2$ subject to inequality constraints

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

> Given $a_1$ and $a_2$ such that $a_1\geq a_2\geq1$, solve the following problem in variables $x_1, x_2, y$
>
> $$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & x_1+x_2\\\text{subject to} & x_1x_2\geq a_1,\\&\frac{x_1x_2}{y}\geq a_2,\\&x_1\geq y\geq x_2>0\end{array}$$

---

My attempt:

First rewrite the problem:

\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & x_1+x_2\\ x_1,x_2,y\\\text{subject to} & x_1x_2\geq a_1,\\&x_1x_2\geq ya_2,\\&x_1\geq y,\\&y\geq x_2,\\&x_2>0.\end{array}
Lagrange multiplier:

$L(x_1,x_2,y,\lambda_i)=x_1+x_2+\lambda_1(a_1-x_1x_2)+\lambda_2(ya_2-x_1x_2)+\lambda_3(y-x_1)+\lambda_4(x_2-y)-\lambda_5x_2.$

$\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial{L}}{\partial{x_1}} \\ \frac{\partial{L}}{\partial{x_2}} \\  \frac{\partial{L}}{\partial{y}}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1-\lambda_1x_2-\lambda_2x_2-\lambda_3 \\ 1-\lambda_1x_1-\lambda_2x_1+\lambda_4-\lambda_5 \\  \lambda_2a_2+\lambda_3-\lambda_4\end{bmatrix}\Longrightarrow\begin{cases} x_2=\frac{1+\lambda_3}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}, \\ x_1=\frac{1+\lambda_4-\lambda_5}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2},\\\lambda_4=a_2\lambda_2+\lambda_3. \end{cases}$

$g(\lambda) = \inf_{x_1,x_2,y} L(x_1,x_2,y,\lambda_i) = \frac{1+\lambda_4-\lambda_5}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}+\frac{1+\lambda_3}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}+\lambda_1(a_1-\frac{1+\lambda_4-\lambda_5}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}\frac{1+\lambda_3}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2})-\lambda_2\frac{1+\lambda_4-\lambda_5}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}\frac{1+\lambda_3}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}-\lambda_3\frac{1+\lambda_4-\lambda_5}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}+\lambda_4\frac{1+\lambda_3}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}-\lambda_5\frac{1+\lambda_3}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}.$

Dual problem:

\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & g(\lambda) \\\quad \lambda\\ \text{subject to} & \lambda_i \geq 0,\\&\lambda_4=a_2\lambda_2+\lambda_3. \end{array}

Comment: Think of the determinant of a $2 \times 2$ matrix.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo if possible analytically, if not then numerically.

Comment: Try to solve it geometrically, It is very easy geometrically speaking, but with KKT there are $2^4$ different cases for slackness which is gonna be hard.

Comment: @K.K.McDonald what do you mean by "solve it geometrically?"

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo actually I came from that direction, original problem was formulated as determinant.

Comment: Look at Sylvester's criterion, then. Your two inequality constraints can be rewritten as linear matrix inequalities (LMIs), which can then be merged into a single LMI. Since the objective is linear, you have a semidefinite program, which should not be hard to solve numerically.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, I still cannot see how the Sylvester's criterion is used here. I already know that if I rewrite the problem in terms of determinant, the matrix is positive definite. Can you please clarify?

Comment: From Sylvester's criterion, the LMI $$\begin{bmatrix} x_1 & \sqrt{a_1}\\ \sqrt{a_1} & x_2\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0$$ contains the inequalities $x_1 \geq 0$, $x_2 \geq 0$ and $x_1 x_2 \geq a_1$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I did this:\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & x_1+x_2\\\text{subject to} & \begin{bmatrix} x_1 & \sqrt{a_1}\\ \sqrt{a_1} & x_2\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0,\\&\begin{bmatrix} \frac{x_1}{\sqrt y} & \sqrt{a_2}\\ \sqrt{a_2} & \frac{x_2}{\sqrt y}\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0.\end{array} But I am missing the third constraint $x_1\geq y\geq x_2$

Comment: If you don't use @ I am not notified of replies. The 2nd one is wrong. It is not an LMI. You have to use some trick like $z := \sqrt{y}$ and move $z$ to the off-diagonals. The 3rd constraint is the conjunction of two linear inequality constraints, which is easy. Once all is done, you have a (convex) semidefinite program that can be solved using, say, CVX or CVXPY.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Let $z=\sqrt{y}$, then \begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & x_1+x_2\\\text{subject to} & \begin{bmatrix} x_1 & \sqrt{a_1}\\ \sqrt{a_1} & x_2\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0,\\&\begin{bmatrix} x_1 & \sqrt{a_2}z\\ \sqrt{a_2}z & x_2\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0,,\\&\begin{bmatrix} x_1 & z\\ z & 1\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0.\end{array}

eventhough $x_1\geq y\geq x_2$ was linear, but after we introduce $z$, it becomes $x_1\geq z^2\geq x_2$ nonlinear. How to transform $z^2\geq x_2$ to LMI?

Comment: @Lee I don't understand the need for the 3rd LMI. I would let the linear inequalities stay as they are. Only the nonlinear ones need to be LMI-fied.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo thank you, I managed to use CVX. Answer below is indeed correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to minimize $x_1+x_2$ and $x_1,x_2 \ge 0$, so we have to get close to origin as much as possible. Consider the problems in $x_1-x_2$ plane, first we have to find the feasible region (I am assuming $a_1,a_2\ge0$):

[image]

The blue curve is the boundary of the first inequality $x_1 x_2 \ge a_1$, the feasible region is the region above this curve. The dashed-line orange curves are the second inequality $x_1x_2\ge ya_2$ for different values of $y$, again the area above these curves are the feasible region. This means if $y\le\frac{a_1}{a_2}$, we can ignore the second inequality, otherwise (if $y\ge\frac{a_1}{a_2}$) we can ignore the first inequality. The purple vector shows the direction of movement of curves as we increase $y$. Then we have the third inequality $x_1 \ge y$ which has the boundary of green line, our answer is in the right hand side of green line. And finally we have the forth inequality $x_2 \le y$ with boundary of grey line, our answer is in lower half of this line (below grey line).

With these information at hand, we see that the inequality $x_1\ge y$ must become active at solution point, this means the slackness condition $\lambda_4(y-x_1)=0$ is equivalent to $x_1=y$. Substituting this in the primal, we get three inequalities $x_2 \ge \frac{a_1}{y}$, $y\ge x_2$ and $x_2 \ge a_2$ and the objective is $y+x_2=x_1+x_2$.

Back to primal. Now consider on one hand we have we have $y\ge x_2$ and $x_2 \ge \frac{a_1}{y}$ which means $y \ge \frac{a_1}{y}$ or $y \ge \sqrt{a_1}$. On the other hand we have $y\ge x_2$ and $x_2 \ge a_2$which means $y\ge a_2$. Thus we obtain two main conditions that solves everything:  $y \ge \sqrt{a_1}$ and $y\ge a_2$.

Finally if $a_2 \le \sqrt{a_1}$ the solution is $x_1=y=x_2=\sqrt{a_1}$. Otherwise if $\sqrt{a_1} \le a_2$ the solution is $x_1=x_2=y=a_2$. And now we can see the funny part, both $x_1 \ge y$ and $y \ge x_2$ are tight so from start we could have considered the slackness conditions $\lambda_3(y-x_1)=0$ and $\lambda_4(x_2-y)=0$ to be active i.e. $x_1=x_2=y$ to be true and get the solution.

Comment: thank you! this is correct, I got the same results in simulation