# Find the Lagrangian dual solution for the primal $\min_{x,y,z}(x+y-z)$ subject to $x-y-3z=1$ and $x,y,z\ge0$

Tags: calculus, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I want to solve the dual problem of the given primal

\begin{equation*} 
\begin{array}{ll@{}ll} 
{\underset{x,y,z}{minimize}}  & x+y-z &\\ 
\text{subject to}& x-y-3z=1   \\ 
                 & x,y,z \geq 0 
\end{array} 
\end{equation*}

The Lagrangian is
\begin{equation*} 
L(x,y,z,\lambda_1,\lambda_2, \lambda_3, \kappa) = (x+y-z) - \lambda_1x -\lambda_2y - \lambda_3z + \kappa(x-y-3z-1) 
\end{equation*}

and the dual function is

\begin{equation*} 
L_{dual}(x,y,z,\lambda_1,\lambda_2, \lambda_3, \kappa) = \max_{x,y,z}(x+y-z) - \lambda_1x -\lambda_2y - \lambda_3z + \kappa(x-y-3z-1) 
\end{equation*}

So the dual problem is
\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & L_{dual}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2, \lambda_3, \kappa) \\
\text{subject to} & \lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3 \geq 0
\end{array}

KKT conditions are:

\begin{equation*} 
\begin{array}{ll@{}ll} 
&\nabla_x L(x,y,z,\lambda_1,\lambda_2, \lambda_3, \kappa) = 1 - \lambda_1 + \kappa = 0\\ 
&\nabla_y L(x,y,z,\lambda_1,\lambda_2, \lambda_3, \kappa) = 1 - \lambda_2 - \kappa = 0\\ 
&\nabla_z L(x,y,z,\lambda_1,\lambda_2, \lambda_3, \kappa) = -1 - \lambda_3 - 3 \kappa = 0\\ 
&\\ 
&\nabla_{\lambda_1} L(x,y,z,\lambda_1,\lambda_2, \lambda_3, \kappa) = -x \leq 0\\ 
&\nabla_{\lambda_2} L(x,y,z,\lambda_1,\lambda_2, \lambda_3, \kappa) = -y \leq 0\\ 
&\nabla_{\lambda_3} L(x,y,z,\lambda_1,\lambda_2, \lambda_3, \kappa) = -z \leq 0\\ 
&\nabla_{\kappa} L(x,y,z,\lambda_1,\lambda_2, \lambda_3, \kappa) = x-y-3z-1 = 0 \\
&\\
&\lambda_1(-x) = 0 \\
&\lambda_2(-y) = 0 \\
&\lambda_3(-z) = 0 \\
&\\
&\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3 \ge 0
\end{array} 
\end{equation*}

Now I want to get $x,y,z$ to set them into the dual function and this is where my problem is, because I don't know what I'm doing here.

First I solved the first 3 derivatives after  $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$, so I get

\begin{equation*} 
\begin{array}{ll@{}ll} 
&\lambda_1 = 1+\kappa \\ 
&\lambda_2 = 1-\kappa \\ 
&\lambda_3 = -(1+\kappa) 
\end{array} 
\end{equation*}

and put them into the complementary condition

\begin{equation*} 
\begin{array}{ll@{}ll} 
&(1+\kappa)(-x) = 0 \\ 
&(1-\kappa)(-y) = 0 \\ 
&(-(1+\kappa))(-z) = 0 
\end{array} 
\end{equation*}

Normally this should help, but I don't know further, could someone help a little bit?

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3503754/173147, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3634821/173147

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By drawing the feasible region, it was possible to see that the maximum couldn't be reached. We have that, for $t>0$, $(x_{t},y_{t},z_{t}) = (2,1,0)^{T} + t (1,1,0)^{T} \geq (0,0,0)^{T}$ is feasible, but the objective function's value is $x_{t}+y_{t}-z_{t}=3+2t$, which increases indefinitely.